# How to Test Get With Single Id in Feathers using POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, postman, feathersjs

I just read the Feathers documentation

https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services

There is a GET method, but I have no idea how I can test the Get Method using POSTMAN. It seems that If I also include some parameters, it still doesn't work. It always returns FIND method available in Feathers

This is the screenshot from POSTMAN

[image]

This is the class and method in the message service

```
class Service {
    constructor (options) {
      this.options = options || {};
    }

    async find (params) {
      // return [];
      return params.query;
    }

    async get (id , installment = null) {

      let installmentOption = installment; 

      if (installmentOption === 1 ){
          return "Succeed"; 
      }








    }

    async create (data, params) {
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        return Promise.all(data.map(current => this.create(current, params)));
      }

      return data;
    }

    async update (id, data, params) {
      return data;
    }

    async patch (id, data, params) {
      return data;
    }

    async remove (id, params) {
      return { id };
    }
  }

  module.exports = function (options) {
    return new Service(options);
  };

  module.exports.Service = Service;
```

I don't know why it always returns params.query not "Succeed".

Does anyone know the solution?

Thanks

Comment: what you are doing is `find` and not `get`.

My suggestion is that create a hook that will check the `method` and `path` of the request. You can add this in your app level all hook.

Comment: Postman giving proper response as you shown in screen, there would be something wrong with implementation

Answer (score 2):

With the REST adapter, the `get` method maps to `<servicename>/<id>` so what  you want to test is `/messages/2`. This is also documented in the [REST client HTTP API usage](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/rest.html#http-api).